# get string for config.php file like wordpress do

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I have two files, `test.php` and `db.php`. The test.php file contains a form like this:

```
<form method="get" action="db.php">

 <form method="get" action="db.php">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Dbhost :-
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="dbhost" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Dbname :-
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="dbname" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Dbusername :-
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="dbusername" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password :-
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="pwd" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="sub" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

When I submit the form I want to get its values in `db.php` file. I want values like wordpress does in its config.php file.

Comment: Please put <form> tag with action- db.php and method- post or get

Comment: @vulcanraven OP wrote the form in the code, it just wasn't formatted for markdown. OP: you opened the form twice, I hope that's just a typo here, not in your original code...And why is this question tagged OOP and XML?

Answer (score 1):

Depending of your  `method` attribute (it can be either `GET` or `POST`), values submitted will be available in your PHP script in superglobal arrays [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

That is, to take, for example, value of field named `dbhost`, you can write in `db.php` the following:

```
echo $_GET['dbhost'];
```

of (if you have `<form method="post">`),

```
echo $_POST['dbhost'];
```

You can also assign received values to variables like this:

```
$dbuser = $_GET['dbusername'];
$dbpassword = $_GET['pwd'];
$dbname = $_GET['dbname'];
$dbhost = $_GET['dbhost'];
```

and after that use `$dbuser`, `$dbpassword`, `$dbname`, `$dbhost` variables to connect to database.

Comment: when i submit the form i want that form value in db.php file  like     Dbhost = "xyz" , Dbusername = "admin" ...if you know the wordpress when we fill db form than it's config.php file get value automaticly..

Comment: Its not so clear, what do you want to do. Do you want to create some form, which will set database connection parameters for your wordpress config? If so, one way to do that is to store submitted database parameters into some file on server (you can use [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) functions) and inside wordpress config.php, after database parameter definitions, load database parameters from that file (you can use `file_get_contents()` and `unserialize()` functions).

Answer (score 0):

In db.php file, use the following code snippet:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET["sub"])) // check if button was not pressed on the form 
    {
        header("Location: test.php");
    }
    $host     = $_GET["dbhost"];  
    $db       = $_GET["dbname"];  
    $user     = $_GET["dbusername"];
    $password = $_GET["pwd"];

    $connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password); 
    if (!$connection)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
          mysql_select_db($db, $connection);
         // Connection established! Do your work here
    }

    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: k..in that file i want $host  =  "xyz"  , $db  = "admin" etc.. i don't want there $_post[''] i want value of that form in the db.php file..

Comment: sorry sir my English is week..i explain if you work in wordpress when we submit the admin form it's config.php file get automatically get that value           [like]    when i fill test.php form than in db.php file get the value of the form..

Comment: @kushal, do you want db.php page to just *show* the values submitted by test.php page? Also, is there a form on db.php page as well or you just want to show as text?

Comment: the db.php don't have any form sir... it is for connect the database so when fill  the form it  get value in db.php example ...when i insert value in test.php like [like] username =  <input type="text" value="admin">  than in db.php file get the value [like] $username = "admin" etc

Comment: @kushal, I have editted my answer. It should do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

put your form in a file named form.php for example. Then between  block add the line include('db.php'); you can then access the variables in db.php and get and set their values. I have to state that what you want to achieve is not clearly understood.